# Is using the frontend/UI to do GraphQL mutations... anti-pattern?

Tags: vue.js, design-patterns, graphql, apollo

So currently I just have a project that uses Vue.js for my frontend. There's a GraphQL backed by a sqlite database. Vue.js with Apollo Client reads incoming messages from a websocket server and based on that message it performs either a create or update GraphQL mutation. Basically it looks at the message's key and performs a graphql query on that key. If that key exists, update mutation otherwise do a create mutation (insert into table).

This project was just a pet project to learn about GraphQL. So I just told someone I know about this and says letting the UI handle the writes to the DB is anti-pattern. I'm not sure what it means but what are some thoughts? Apollo Client/Vue just really just sends gql queries and the actual writing is handled by the underlying GraphQL Apollo Server.

Technically I guess I could use a separate microservice that writes to the DB directly and not need to do any GraphQL mutations?

Comment: I would be concerned that every websocket message requires _two_ gql calls, a key lookup followed by a mutation. Sounds inefficient.

Comment: @jaco0646 yeah, it's definitely a very subpar implementation but it was really just to play around with different technologies. This was mainly to try and incorporate Kafka with GraphQL and streaming events and how to get them to interact with eachother mainly.

Comment: 'upsert' (update or instert) - update mutation can check if key exists and process differently ... anti-pattern? it depends ... works only when front/page active ... human factor/filter (operator approves only some messages to be stored) ... server can do the same, can have some thread/socket client listening service and update by graphql (if not our DB/service)